# Add handheld touch events to web app

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, touch

What's the best way to add touch events to a web app? The page works well enough on the iPad but it would be nice to have some touch events specific to the handheld devices. Do you recommend any jQuery plugins for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there's little in the way of touch support for jQuery, or indeed any JavaScript library. You'll need to work around platforms that rely on touch.

Even such libraries as [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/) are limited in the sense that it's only for iOS.

Some interesting reading at http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-and-touch-devices

Answer (score 2):

check this out. It's a jQuery plugin that detects touch events like wiping, zooming, scaling and rotation.

http://desmondliang.com/content/touchme-jquery-plugin-ipad-web-apps

Answer (score 1):

**[jqTouch](http://jqtouch.com/)** is your starting point.

You can find demos [here](http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com). It's mostly a GUI framework, but hopefully they'll add stuff like gesture events.